# Is a static function equivalent to a static Func member in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, lambda, static, static-methods

It looks like a **static method** is the same as **static Func field**. Am I missing something, or are they essentially interchangeable (same footprint, etc)?

A static property ends up the same as the other two example, except it includes the (minimal) overhead of the "get" accessor.

Maybe a bit pointless and navel-gazing to ask… but I like to understand what's going on "under the covers", even when it's not immediately relevant.

To be sure: I'm not about to switch all my static methods to lambda expressions (and drive my coworkers crazy). But, there might be some reasonable scenario where a static variable makes more sense than writing a method. Or maybe the opposite: convincing someone to use static methods instead of lambda expressions to make the code more readable or whatever

Plus, I'm curious if there's a better way to investigate these kinds of questions

### My test

I put this simple example into LINQPad (v4.57.02, "compile with */optimize+*" enabled):

```
void Main()
{
    var hold = "this is the thing. it returns true";
    var held = "this is the one that returns false";
    
    Console.WriteLine(One.Check(hold));
    Console.WriteLine(One.Check(held));
    
    Console.WriteLine(Two.Check(hold));
    Console.WriteLine(Two.Check(held));
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class One
{
    public static bool Check(string value)
    {
        return value != null && value.Contains('.');
    }
}

class Two
{
    public static Func<string, bool> Check = v => v != null && v.Contains('.');
}
```

… and it generated the same IL for both. Essentially:

```
XXX.Check:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  brfalse.s   IL_000C
IL_0003:  ldarg.0     
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.s    2E 
IL_0006:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains
IL_000B:  ret         
IL_000C:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000D:  ret         

XXX..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

Comment: You did not make your field `readonly`, so I can do `Two.Check = string.IsNullOrEmpty;`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I missed '= v' part... more coffee needed.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen good point. Not sure whether that's a feature or a bug :) In practice, I'm sure one would wrap it with a Property (well… "in practice" I would use a method, but you know)

Comment: You could do `Two.Check.GetInvocationList();` and `Console.WriteLine(Two.Check);` and so on. The other one can participate in method group conversions, as in `Predicate<string> variable = One.Check;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of any case where there would be a difference in code-gen for the method (the explicitly written method or the lambda body). There might be a weird (or by-design) corner case in the C# compiler but that's not essential. Such corner cases can arise because lambdas must be lowered into methods before emitting an assembly. This lowering stage might introduce (hopefully inconsequential) changes.

The main point to note about lambda code-gen is that lambdas can close over variables. This requires the generated method to become an instance method on a generated class. Here, the form of the lambdas you're writing will never cause this.

In recent C# compiler versions the generated method is an instance method on a dummy type. This makes delegate calls faster (which is unintuitive because more arguments are faster in this case).

Invoking such a "fake" static method is a delegate call and the .NET JIT has no facilities to optimize that away. (It could, for instance, runtime specialize the call site to a known delegate target. The JVM does this for virtual calls. It inlines right through virtual calls. The Hotspot JIT is very advanced.) This means that you have indirect call overhead and loose inlining and also all follow-up optimizations.

If not necessary this should never be done. It might be useful if you want to plug in different methods at runtime. Or, maybe these static `Func` variables can act as a cache. Or, you can rewire them in the debugger.

The `get` accessor of any such static property should be exactly zero-cost because tiny methods are reliably inlined.

Another slight performance drawback is increased type load and initialization time. Also, more objects hanging around slowing down *all* future G2 collections.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious answer is that no, they're not.

```
Two.Check = v => { throw new Exception(); };
```

The IL code generated for the methods is the same, as you're still defining the same implementation, but changing the way it's referenced.

Even if `Check` were `readonly`, you could still do this:

```
class Two
{
    public static readonly Func<string, bool> Check;
    static Two()
    {
        if (Helper.IsBlueMoon && Helper.IsFirst)
        {
            Check = v => { throw new Exception(); };
        } else {
            Check = v => v != null && v.Contains('.');
        }
    }
}
```

One other important thing to note is that arguments are not named when using `Func<string, bool>`, and you cannot use [XML Documentation Comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)

Comment: oh right. it's a delegate, which relates differently… even if the actual implementations are the same. similar to what so, similar to what @JeppeStigNielsen was getting at in the OP comments